# PHP Query not returning data correctly

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a query that pulls values from multiple tables. I want to order them by shows_date ASC only I cant seem to get it to ouput any data, Can anybody see a problem with my syntax?

```
$artists = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . GIGPRESS_ARTISTS . " AS a, " . GIGPRESS_SHOWS . " AS s, ORDER BY s.show_date ");

var_dump($artists);

foreach($artists as $artist_group) 
{
    $shows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * 
                                 FROM " . GIGPRESS_ARTISTS . " AS a, " . GIGPRESS_VENUES . " as v, " . GIGPRESS_SHOWS ." AS s 
                                 LEFT JOIN  " . GIGPRESS_TOURS . " AS t 
                                   ON s.show_tour_id = t.tour_id 
                                 WHERE " . $date_condition . " 
                                   AND show_status != 'deleted' AND s.show_artist_id = " . $artist_group->artist_id . " 
                                   AND s.show_artist_id = a.artist_id AND s.show_venue_id = v.venue_id " . $further_where . " 
                                 ORDER BY s.show_date " . $sort . ",s.show_expire " . $sort . ",s.show_time ". $sort . $limit);
}
```

---

DUMP RETURNS

array(72) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#260 (25) { ["artist_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["artist_name"]=> string(14) "Damien Dempsey" ["artist_order"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_artist_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_venue_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_tour_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_date"]=> string(10) "2012-01-29" ["show_multi"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_time"]=> string(8) "20:30:00" ["show_expire"]=> string(10) "2012-01-29" ["show_price"]=> string(7) "£10.00" ["show_tix_url"]=> string(0) "" ["show_tix_phone"]=> string(0) "" ["show_ages"]=> string(8) "All Ages" ["show_notes"]=> string(0) "" ["show_related"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_status"]=> string(7) "deleted" ["show_tour_restore"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_address"]=> NULL ["show_locale"]=> NULL ["show_country"]=> NULL ["show_venue"]=> NULL ["show_venue_url"]=> NULL ["show_venue_phone"]=> NULL } [1]=> object(stdClass)#259 (25) { ["artist_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["artist_name"]=> string(10) "Gary Dunne" ["artist_order"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_artist_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_venue_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_tour_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_date"]=> string(10) "2012-01-29" ["show_multi"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_time"]=> string(8) "20:30:00" ["show_expire"]=> string(10) "2012-01-29" ["show_price"]=> string(7) "£10.00" ["show_tix_url"]=> string(0) "" ["show_tix_phone"]=> string(0) "" ["show_ages"]=> string(8) "All Ages" ["show_notes"]=> string(0) "" ["show_related"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_status"]=> string(7) "deleted" ["show_tour_restore"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_address"]=> NULL ["show_locale"]=> NULL ["show_country"]=> NULL ["show_venue"]=> NULL ["show_venue_url"]=> NULL ["show_venue_phone"]=> NULL } [2]=> object(stdClass)#261 (25) { ["artist_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["artist_name"]=> string(19) "London Irish Centre" ["artist_order"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_artist_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_venue_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["show_tour_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_date"]=> string(10) "2012-01-29" ["show_multi"]=> string(1) "0" ["show_time"]=> string(8) "20:30:00" ["show_expire"]=> string(10) "2012-01-29" ["show_price"]=> string(7) "£10.00" ["show_tix_url"]=> string(0) "" ["show_tix_phone"]=> string(0) "" ["show_ages"]=> string(8) "All Ages"

---

Ive tried the following

```
foreach($artists as $artist_group) {
        $shows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . GIGPRESS_ARTISTS . " AS a, " . GIGPRESS_VENUES . " as v, " . GIGPRESS_SHOWS ." AS s LEFT JOIN  " . GIGPRESS_TOURS . " AS t ON s.show_tour_id = t.tour_id WHERE " . $date_condition . " AND show_status != 'deleted' ORDER BY s.show_date ASC " . $limit);
```

Which works in regards to the ordering, but it outputs each value about 100 times or something stupid..

Comment: What your `var_dump()` returns?

Comment: What is the error message? var_dump the foreach loop aswell.

Comment: You sure have you have successful connection?

Comment: Yes if I remove the table join and just pull everything from the artists table it works fine, only doesnt order my output by date...

Comment: @DanielWest how do I dump my foreach sorry?

Comment: So you made a join. And where is a join condition? How tables are supposed to be joined? For now you just get cartesian production, which makes no sense for you

Comment: @Liam You just need to do a var_dump of the result within the foreach loop.

Comment: @Liam For the 100 times per item, this is always caused by a bad MySQL join. Maybe a left Join is not what you really need. If the data needs to exist in BOTH tables then an INNER JOIN would be more appropriate. A LEFT JOIN basically means keep everything on the left table of the join even if it doesn't exist in the other (right) table. This might be your problem.

Comment: @Daniel West: his problem is that he didn't specify join condition for the first query

Comment: @zerkms Yeah you are right, but I thought he had fixed that due to the database output he was getting.

Comment: @Daniel West: I suppose that he didn't even check if output is expected: "there is something, ok, let's do the next" ;-)

Comment: @zerkms Probably... but we all do it sometimes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the comma after AS s, is extraneous

> SELECT * FROM " . GIGPRESS_ARTISTS . " AS **a,** " . GIGPRESS_SHOWS .
>   " AS s, ORDER BY s.show_date

additionally you seem to be missing a WHERE clause or a JOIN ON statement.

this query would produce a cross-join with (all gigs) x (all bands) so that in your foreach you will process each band once for every gig in the system, instead of once for each band/show.

Comment: Wondered how with such syntax error his `var_dump` returns data :-S

Answer (score 0):

Well you definitely have a result, however it's returning an array of objects with each object being a row returned and not a multidimensional array as you might be expecting.

To get the data within the object you should be able to do something like this:

```
//initlialise array
$array = array();

//loop through array of objects
foreach($artists as $row){
    $temp_array = array();
    $temp_array['artist_id'] = $row->artist_id;
    $temp_array['artist_name'] = $row->artist_name;
    ....
    //add rest of object data to temporary array
    ....
    //assign data to main array
    $array[] = $temp_array;
}
```

This will then get the data from the objects and create a multidimensional array of the data. You may want to process your data there and then. This is only an example as I do not know how you wish to use the data.

P.S. As zerkms says, you could access the data by using `$array[4]->artist_name` if you wish but I misunderstood your question. You could use the code above however if you really need to store it as a multidimensional array.

You need to add a JOIN condition to the first SQL statement if you haven't fixed that already, without it you will be receiving the Cartesian join which will be giving you duplicate rows as you have provided no join condition. This will solve the problem of having 100x rows the same. There is also a comma not needed for the last condition before the ORDER which has already been mentioned as this will cause an SQL syntax error.

Comment: @zerkms Well it is as it creates an array of arrays. As you could then do $array[4]['artist_name'] to get the 5th entry's artist name...

Comment: @Daniel West: how is it better than `$array[4]->artist_name`?

Comment: @zerkms Its not, I prefer using OO. I thought he was having problems using PHP objects.